# Figuring out domain name for generating Customer Signing Request (CSR)

Tags: domains, openssl, certificate-generation

I access production and qa domain websites as follows :

**Production :** `https://portal.mydomain.com`

**QA  :** `https://portal-qa.mydomain.com`

However, when I add `www` like the following :`https://www.portal-qa.mydomain.com`, I get "Web Page Not" available error on the browser.

Since I have been following the steps for generating CSR using OpenSSL as mentioned [here](https://www.alphassl.com/support/create-csr/apache.html)

They have mentioned domain name as `www.mydomain.com`.

**My QUESTION:**

Is it okay if I use `portal.mydomain.com` and `portal-qa.mydomain.com` as my fully qualified domain name(FQDN) without using `www` for generating the CSR? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you have purchase a standard, single domain SSL certificate, then
>   it will be for one domain, so you can only use it for domainname.com
>   or www.domainname.com.
>
> If you have purchased a wildcard or UCC certificate then it will allow
>   either unlimited subdomains (in the case of a wildcard) or mulitple
>   domains up to a certain number (in the case of UCC).

https://serverfault.com/questions/226289/how-to-install-a-single-ssl-certificate-for-www-and-non-www

Comment: Yes, I will be going to purchase it for one domain only. I am wondering if not adding `www` to the Common Name would make any difference?

Comment: @John Steve is correct, most SSL certificates will cover one or the other, so most sites just redirect one to the other. That way you'll avoid issues with duplicate content as well. There are a few providers that issue SSL's that cover both, see [this](https://www.clickssl.net/blog/do-i-need-different-ssl-certificates-for-www-non-www-domain) for more info about that. For the different subdomains (which actually `www` is considered to be as well), you'll need a UCC certificate. A cheap (free) alternative to all the above is just to use a CDN that offers a "flexible" SSL, such as CloudFlare.

Comment: @dan  I am planning to get domain validated certificate from Globalsign( AlphaSSL). Since we don't use www, I think it wouldn't make sense to use a service which uses both.

Comment: If you don't use `www`, there really is no need. For example, even Google redirects their `non-www` domain to `www`. Most do this to avoid from having to manage both, and to not confuse search engines. The reason to get one with both would be if you need to serve _different_ content from both (such as for an intranet or application).